# What are the capabilities of current Boolean Satisfiability Solvers?

Tags: np-hardness, complexity-classes, p-vs-np, ai.artificial-intel, boolean-formulas

I am wondering how well current Boolean Satisfiability solvers are able to perform — for example, are the best SATsolvers able to solve problems from SATlib?

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about *theoretical* computer science.  Also, this seems too vague and open-ended to be answerable.  It's not clear how you imagine to measure "how well".  If you want to know whether SAT solvers can solve problems in SATlib, the best way to find out is probably to try it.

Comment: Search for the most recent SAT competition results to get an idea.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please edit this question to summarize the algorithm(s) that your investigation shows Boolean satisfiability solves (e.g., SATlib et. al.) are based upon fundamentally.  Then try to ascertain whether that technology's limit in practice is due to the algorithm itself or engineering lack of wisdom when implementing it.  For limits of the algorithm, please identify in the edited question what you find perplexing or an area of theoretical research.  Indeed, please edit the question: with why isn't Algorithm B utilized instead of limited Algorithm A?